# is $\frac{x^{2}-4}{x-2}$ Riemann integrable in [1,3]?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, riemann-integration

\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{x^{2}-4}{x-2}
\end{align*}
As this function is not defined at 2. what would we say about the Riemann integrability in [1,3] interval?
As per the conditions, Riemann integration is only for bounded functions. So Do we need to redefine the function to call it as Riemann integrable? By assigning the limit value or by some fixed number. or Can we say this is Riemann integrable without redefining it, means by break-ing the given interval into [1,2) and (2,3]?

Comment: check your spelling of *Riemann*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Edited. Thank you.

Comment: If this is for a class, you should probably check carefully how Riemann integrable is defined there. It doesn't cause problems to ignore isolated problem points when defining Riemann integrability, but I don't know if this is the standard definition.

Comment: I would say no for Riemann integrability, simply because the function is not defined at 2.

Comment: I would say yes and that it is only required to be undefined at a finite number of points (ensuring the points are isolated and don't affect the calculation), I think this follows the "area" intuition of Riemann Integration. But definitions are different depending on the text.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp A bounded function is Riemann integrable if the set of points of discontinuity is finite or A bounded function s integrable in [a,b] if the set of its points of discontinuity has a finite number of limit points. In those cases, We can neglect those points as their contribution to Oscillatory sum is negligible. But here the case is, the function itself is not defined at a point in the interval in which we are checking for the integrability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of Riemann integrable function from an interval $[a,b]$ into $\Bbb R$ is only defined for bounded functions from $[a,b]$ into $\Bbb R$. Since the domain of your function is $[1,3]\setminus\{2\}$, then the definition does not apply; your function neither is nor isn't Riemann integrable.

You can look at is is an improper integral: compute $\lim_{x\to2^-}\int_1^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt$ and $\lim_{x\to2^+}\int_x^3f(t)\,\mathrm dt$. It happens that both limits exist; then $\int_1^3f(t)\,\mathrm dt$ is their sum.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2 - 4 = (x-2)(x+2)$

So:

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = x+2,$$
***everywhere $f$ is defined***.

You technically can't say that $f$ is Riemann integrable since as you said, Riemann integrability is only defined for bounded, everywhere defined functions on closed intervals. But since $f(x) = x+2$ everywhere except a point (at which $f$ is not even defined) and integration is unchanged if you change a function by a point, there isn't any harm in thinking $\int_1^3 f(x) dx = \int_1^3 x+2 \ dx$.

On the other hand you could also go about defining it using the improper integrals, i.e. $\int_1^3 f(x) dx := \lim_{a \to 2} \int_1^a f(x) dx  + \lim_{b \to 2} \int_b^3 f(x) dx$.

This will give you the same answer.

Technical annoyances like this is why we define generalizations of the Riemann integral, like the [Lebesgue integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration).

Answer (score 0):

Yes  for Reimann Integrability you have to assign a value for $X=2$ and you can assign any real number at that point.
Other wise you can use concept of improper integrals..

Answer (score 0):

It depends, the function is undefined at $x=2$, although we can ignore it if we want.

Clearly the function is continuous everywhere else, and therefore it is integrable if we don't pay attention to that fact.